# jQuery UI's sortable() for Tables with rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a way for jQuery UI's sortable() to sort rows only by their "containing" element? I have a table with rowspanned cells that are only supposed to be sorted in their containing spanned columns.

```
var $sortable = $('.nested-sortable tbody');
$sortable.sortable({
    helper: function (e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function () {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwch19no/)

The column **Make** isn't sortable. The column **Type** should only be sortable within its "container", which is the **Make** column. This means that Types 1 and 2 cannot be dropped to Brand 2 and Type 3 cannot be dropped to Brand 1. The same is true for the Subtypes and models.

[image]

Is it possible for jQuery UI sortable out of the box? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to do it in `table` tag?

Comment: @stanley1943 if there's a way to do it other than using a table tag with it maintaining that look, then I guess it's fine.

Comment: im actually really curious to find out. If i got time at work, i'll take a shot at it. I strongly believe you must use `div` on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I just needed to add another tbody selector to make it work:

```
$(function(){
    var $sortable = $('.nested-sortable tbody tbody');
    $sortable.sortable({
        axis:'y',
        helper: function (e, ui) {
            ui.children().each(function () {
                $(this).width($(this).width());
            });
            return ui;
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwch19no/1/)